# Hashlib MemoryError in Python 3.5 but not in 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib, functools

I've been porting a set of Python 2.7 scripts to Python 3.5 so that I can use some libraries that aren't available in 2.7, but I'm getting MemoryError from this code that worked previously:

```
import hashlib, functools
sha2h = hashlib.sha256()
with open('/path/to/any/file', 'rb') as f:
        [sha2h.update(chunk) for chunk in iter(functools.partial(f.read, 256), '')]
```

As far as I can tell, this is the proper way to get a SHA256 hash of a file. I can't seem to find anything about this issue. If it helps, here's the traceback when the above code is run from the shell:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
```

Also tried replacing

```
sha2h = hashlib.sha256()
```

with

```
sha2h = hashlib.new('sha256')
```

to match the documentation for hashlib, but this yielded no change in outcome.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Python 3, you need to set `b''` instead of `''` as the sentinel value for the `iter` call:

```
iter(functools.partial(f.read, 256), b'')
```

You also really shouldn't be using a list comprehension for side effects like this, but if you're porting existing code that does that, it's probably best to just leave that for now.

Comment: Thank you! This change fixed my issue.

Comment: Embarrassingly, this is code that I originally wrote - my overly ambitious "Hello world" project. If you're feeling extra helpful towards this Python newbie, could you suggest (or link to) a more proper way of doing this?

Comment: @Nstr10: Use a normal `for` loop.